# Can I use In-App-Purchases when distributing outside of Apple's App Store?

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm new to mac os app development and the documentation doesn't ever say that this is not supported (as far as I could tell).

- Can I use IAPs if I don't submit to the App Store?
- Is there anything different that I should do to setup IAPs when distributing outside of the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is not possible, as documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/macos/distribution/

Only iCloud and Push Notifications are available.

Answer (score 0):

I think its possible by following instructions below.

Go to itunesConnect , Users and Roles, Create a sandbox user . I am thinking you have already made the in app purchase items in your app in itunes connect. Now in your device log out the Appstore ID from settings. Do the in app purchase using the Test user credentials you created, and it will make the in app using a sandbox environment.

For more info about In App follow this link :
https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial